# Array of props gives undefined inside a component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From one of my React component i used like this which gives the correct array in console.

```
console.log(this.state.pintype[0]);
return (
  <div>
    <PinType {...this.state.pintype[0]} />
  </div>
)
```

My PinType component is

```
import React from 'react';

class PinType extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        attr : this.props.attributes
    };

}
render() {
    console.log(this.state.attr);
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.attr}
        </div>
        )
   }
}

export default PinType;
```

The prop array actually contains a key named attributes. But the console(this.state.attr) returns undefined. How can i solve this?

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(this.state.pintype[0])` ?

Comment: attributes
:
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
pin_id
:
1
pin_name
:
"Tree"

Comment: did you get `attributes` key in that json ? If yes then it won't work as you expecting. In this case just try with `<PinType attributes = this.state.pintype[0].attributes />`

Comment: Yes. my json gives three keys such as pin_id, pin_name and attributes which is again an array. I tried as you mentioned and got error 'Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined'

Comment: it seems like you don't need to pass index `0`. So please try without indexing and that would be `<PinType attributes = {this.state.pintype.attributes} />`

Comment: this.state.pintype is an array and i just passed the first array using the key [0] to the new component

Comment: can you create a `fiddle`, `TeamViewer` or anything so I can see by myself ?

Comment: Can you try in the same way to retrieve a nested array in a new component. This is the requirement. I'm not familiar with creating react in jsfiddle.

Comment: `<PinType attributes= {this.state.pintype[0]} />` will work, I guess

Comment: attributes= {this.state.pintype[0]} and {...this.state.pintype[0]} gives same result undefined

Comment: Also the React chrome extension shows the values of Props correctly.

Comment: How are you getting `this.state.pintype` ? Can you show the entire component ?

Comment: might be a problem getting the props , try setting the props to your state in `componentwillreceiveprops` and if you are still facing issue let us know

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to use `props` in your constructor instead of `this.props` :</strike>

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        attr : props.attributes
    };
}
```

Or use `this.props` directly in `render` :

```
class PinType extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
          <div>
             {this.props.attributes}
          </div>
      )
   }
}
```

**Edit** : As Michal said in comment, using props in constructor after `super()` is not a good practice.

If `this.props.attributes` is working in render i assume you are getting your data after the component is mounted (probably fetched data), so you should either in the parent or in the children handle the render when the request is pending and when there's an error :

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.pintype ? (this.state.pintype.error ? <p>ERROR</p> : <PinType {...this.state.pintype[0]} />) : <p>LOADING</p> }
    </div>
  )
```

Change this according to the way you fetch your data.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. After you call `super(props)` props should be defined. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: this.props directly in render gives the values

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <PinType attributes={this.state.pintype[0]} />
  </div>
)
```